# Unable to getValue with DJIParam keys

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to read the values like serialnumber, model, battery from a connected DJI drone (Spark) with the iOS SDK. For example I'm doing:

```
if let serialKey = DJIProductKey(param: DJIParamSerialNumber) {
            DJISDKManager.keyManager()?.getValueFor(serialKey, withCompletion: { (value, error) in
           ....
        })
        }
```

However I'm getting an error: Optional(Current product does not support this feature.(code:-1013))
Might this because I' running a setup with the bridge app and xcode simulator? Or is it that the Spark just does not support some of the keys?

The setup I have is the Remote controller connected to an iphone running the bridge app. A DJI Spark drone turned on and running the application in an iphone X simulator with in the appRegisteredWithError delegate the DJISDKManager.enableBridgeMode(withBridgeAppIP: "xxx.xxx.x.xx") option. Running the application gives both lights green in the bridge app.

Answer (score 1):

Spark should support the `DJIParamSerialNumber` and `DJIProductParamModelName` keys.

To check if a product supports a certain key, you can call `DJIKeyManager.isKeySupported` and check for it.

Comment: Ok I will check is the key is supported... if not, you would reckon it as a bug?

Comment: @tapmonkey Can you give us some more information about the setup? Are you using a RC? How does the device running the bridge app communicate with both your computer and the Spark / Spark RC wifi?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem turned out very simple to fix, instead of using DJIProductKey it should be DJIFlightControllerKey and it will perfectly find the serial from the drone.